# Reading decimal field from Parquet file in Java

Tags: java, parquet

I read a parquet file as follows,

```
Builder<GenericRecord> builder = AvroParquetReader.builder(path);
ParquetReader<GenericRecord> reader = builder.build();

GenericRecord record = null;
while((record = reader.read()) != null) {
  System.out.println(record.toString());
}
```

Output:

```
{"var1": "ABCD", "var2": "1234567", "var3": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 113, 15, 120, -111, -92, -114, -112, 50]}
```

Any type cast I try to do on the byte array value

```
(byte[]) record.get("var3")
```

throws

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Fixed cannot be cast to [B
```

How can I convert this GenericData back to Decimal?

Parquet file schema:

```
-bash-4.1$ parquet-tools schema my-parquet-file.gz.parquet
message spark_schema {
optional binary var1 (UTF8);
optional int64 var2;
optional fixed_len_byte_array(16) var3 (DECIMAL(38,8));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Was able to do this with a newer version of avro ([Documentation](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.0/api/java/org/apache/avro/Conversions.DecimalConversion.html#fromFixed(org.apache.avro.generic.GenericFixed,%20org.apache.avro.Schema,%20org.apache.avro.LogicalType)))

```
public BigDecimal fromFixed(GenericFixed value,
               Schema schema,
               LogicalType type)
```

is just what I needed.

Comment: Can you provide - besides the API documentation - sample code of how you actually used it to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Using Avro GenericData API:

```
Binary binary = simpleGroup.getBinary(i, 0);
Conversions.DecimalConversion decimalConversions = new Conversions.DecimalConversion();
BigDecimal bigDecimal = decimalConversions.fromFixed(
   new GenericData.Fixed(Schema.create(Schema.Type.DOUBLE), binary.getBytes()), 
   Schema.create(Schema.Type.DOUBLE), 
   LogicalTypes.decimal(38, 10));
```

I prefer the "Spark way":

```
Binary binary = simpleGroup.getBinary(i, 0);
new BigDecimal(new BigInteger(binary.getBytes()), scale);
```